# Run osgi bundle from command line

Tags: java, osgi, bundle

I developed an OSGi bundle, which I usually test from Eclipse. Aftrer exporting the bundle, I get a bundle.jar file. I would like to be able to run the generated file from the command line. Something like:

C:\java -jar bundle.jar osgi_framework path

But, how to include the osgi framework in it? and also, how can I start the bundle immediately?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can start the OSGi framework from the command line as follows. First for Equinox:

```
java -jar org.eclipse.osgi_VERSION.jar -console
```

NB. substitute VERSION for the version of Equinox you have installed. For Felix:

```
java -jar bin/felix.jar
```

Now using the OSGi console, install your own bundle:

```
osgi> install file:/path/to/my/bundle.jar
Bundle ID is 2
```

And start it:

```
osgi> start 2
```

Comment: Hi Neil. I've tried your suggestions and while everything worked as expected with Felix, the same can't be said of Equinox. I tried to execute your "java -jar org.eclipse.osgi_VERSION.jar -console" command but then it just hangs.  Any idea of what might be wrong?

Comment: I've tried to run with -consoleLog and the problem seems to be related with not finding org.eclipse.equinox.console. I don't get it. I just downloaded the latest stable version from Equinox's site.

Answer (score 5):

Though it's a really old question but people are having problems running the osgi console with command `java -jar org.eclipse.osgi.jar -console` since the lack of several bundles needed like the comments to Neil's answer.

See my answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25733843/how-to-start-osgi-console/35922571#35922571) to get the instructions on how to run the osgi console. After osgi console starts, just follow Neil's answer to install your own bundles.