# OSGi console not shown in command line

Tags: java, osgi

I'm trying to get an [OSGi example application](http://www.vogella.com/articles/OSGi/article.html) working, but I'm running into trouble while starting OSGi from the command line.

Note that I don't want to run the bundle in the Eclipse OSGi environment. This works fine.

---

First, I created the example bundle. Afterwards, I tried to run the the application in the command line. To do so, I run the OSGi jar as stated in the above-mentioned article, [official instructions](http://eclipse.org/equinox/documents/quickstart-framework.php) and a [related question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3601079/run-osgi-bundle-from-command-line):

```
$ cd
$ cp /usr/local/eclipse/plugins/org.eclipse.osgi_3.8.2.v20130124-134944.jar
     org.eclipse.osgi.jar
$ java -jar org.eclipse.osgi.jar -console
```

Now, OSGi seems to run, but the console is not shown.

---

According to the above-mentioned article (see Section 4.2) and [a related question with solution](http://www.eclipse.org/forums/index.php/t/340093/), the following additional packages are required:

- org.eclipse.equinox.console
- org.apache.felix.gogo.command
- org.apache.felix.gogo.runtime
- org.apache.felix.gogo.shell

Are they missing? If yes, how do I link them?

---

My question: How can I run OSGi with console in the command line?

Thanks for any help!

**EDIT 1:** `$ eclipse -console -noExit` and closing the IDE works as a workaround :-) sadly, IDE bundles are loaded this way as well.

Comment: So you already linked to the question with the solution. Did you try that?

Comment: What I tried was `java -jar org.eclipse.equinox.console_VERSION.jar`, also called adding `-console`. Ended up in `no main manifest attribute, in org.eclipse.equinox.console_1.0.0.v20120522-1841.jar`. Do I _link_ the bundles?

Comment: To run with Equinox check http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25733843/how-to-start-osgi-console-equinox

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A workaround is not to run Equinox implementation of OSGi [Apache Felix Framework](http://felix.apache.org/downloads.cgi) as stated in the mentioned [related question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3601079/run-osgi-bundle-from-command-line):

- Download the framework.
- Unzip the framework
- Run the following command:

`$ java -jar bin/felix.jar`

---

Anyway, this seems to be a workaround to me and I'm still interested in how to use the Equinox framework from the command line.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a generic command to have it working with Equinox implementation on both Unix and Windows systems.

Tested with an install of Eclipse 2018-12, however it should work with other versions as well.

Go to the plugin directory

Unix, bash:

```
java -Dosgi.bundles=\
$(ls -1 org.apache.felix.gogo.shell_*.jar)@start,\
$(ls -1 org.apache.felix.gogo.command_*.jar)@start,\
$(ls -1 org.apache.felix.gogo.runtime_*.jar)@start,\
$(ls -1 org.eclipse.equinox.console_*.jar)@start\
 -jar $(ls -1 org.eclipse.osgi_*.jar) -console
```

Windows, powershell (works in console mode only):

```
java ('-Dosgi.bundles='+((`
"$(ls org.apache.felix.gogo.shell_*.jar | select -ExpandProperty Name)`@start",`
"$(ls org.apache.felix.gogo.command_*.jar | select -ExpandProperty Name)`@start",`
"$(ls org.apache.felix.gogo.runtime_*.jar | select -ExpandProperty Name)`@start",`
"$(ls org.eclipse.equinox.console_*.jar | select -ExpandProperty Name)`@start"`
) -join ',')) '-jar' "$(ls org.eclipse.osgi_*.jar | select -ExpandProperty Name)" '-console'
```

Windows, powershell (works with ISE as well):

```
Start-Process 'java' -ArgumentList `
(('-Dosgi.bundles=',`
"$(ls org.apache.felix.gogo.shell_*.jar | select -ExpandProperty Name)`@start,",`
"$(ls org.apache.felix.gogo.command_*.jar | select -ExpandProperty Name)`@start,",`
"$(ls org.apache.felix.gogo.runtime_*.jar | select -ExpandProperty Name)`@start,",`
"$(ls org.eclipse.equinox.console_*.jar | select -ExpandProperty Name)`@start",`
" -jar $(ls org.eclipse.osgi_*.jar | select -ExpandProperty Name) -console"
) -join '')
```

Link to the eclipse bug:
[Bug 371101 - Equinox console doesn't start](https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=371101)