# How to start osgi console (Equinox)

Tags: osgi, equinox

I'm trying to start an OSGi console in Windows 7.

I used this statement on a terminal window:

```
java -jar org.eclipse.osgi.jar -console
```

But it doesn't work that is nothing does happen nor doesn't appear prompt `osgi>`. And typing on keyboard is ineffective except for `^C` that makes to reappear usual terminal prompt.

Anyone has any suggestion?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [OSGi console not shown in command line](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19079830/osgi-console-not-shown-in-command-line)

Answer (score 22):

Starting from Equinox 3.8.0.M4, it has a new console. So you need also these four bundles for it to run properly.

1. `org.eclipse.equinox.console.jar`
2. `org.apache.felix.gogo.shell.jar`
3. `org.apache.felix.gogo.command.jar`
4. `org.apache.felix.gogo.runtime.jar`

These jar files can be found in your Eclipse installation folder under 'plugins' folder. Copy these jars and put them in the same folder with your `org.eclipse.osgi.jar` and it would look like:

- somedir/

  - configuration/

    - config.ini
  - org.eclipse.osgi.jar
  - org.eclipse.equinox.console.jar
  - org.apache.felix.gogo.shell.jar
  - org.apache.felix.gogo.command.jar
  - org.apache.felix.gogo.runtime.jar

Then edit `config.ini` as:

`osgi.bundles=org.apache.felix.gogo.runtime@start, org.apache.felix.gogo.command@start, org.apache.felix.gogo.shell@start, org.eclipse.equinox.console@start`

After doing this, run `java -jar org.eclipse.osgi.jar -console` in your command line and the OSGi console will start.

Reference [Bug 371101](https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=371101)

UPDATE 06/2022:

the list of required bundles got longer in the meantime:

```
osgi.bundles= \
    org.apache.felix.gogo.runtime_1.1.4.v20210111-1007.jar@start, \
    org.apache.felix.gogo.command_1.1.2.v20210111-1007.jar@start, \
    org.apache.felix.gogo.shell_1.1.4.v20210111-1007.jar@start, \
    org.eclipse.equinox.console_1.4.500.v20211021-1418.jar@start, \
    org.eclipse.osgi.services_3.10.200.v20210723-0643.jar@start, \
    org.osgi.util.function_1.2.0.202109301733.jar@start, \
    org.osgi.util.promise_1.2.0.202109301733.jar@start, \
```

Note that you can reference the `org.eclipse.osgi` directly in the plugin folder. And if you do so, your configuration folder is in the plugins folder!

```
java -jar plugins\org.eclipse.osgi_3.18.0.v20220516-2155.jar -console
```

Comment: Just tried this with equinox 4.10. I copied everything into a new folder and renamed the jar files (stripped away version), and it worked. Thanks.

Answer (score 6):

The equinox built-in console is deprecated and disabled since version 3.8. If you use a newer version, you should use the osgi.console.enable.builtin=true property. See http://hwellmann.blogspot.hu/2012/08/new-osgi-console-in-equinox-380.html.

You can set these properties as system properties. Your command will be:

```
java -Dosgi.noshutdown=true -Dosgi.console.enable.builtin=true -jar org.eclipse.osgi.jar -console
```

This worked for me with 3.8. I have just tried it with 3.10 but it does not work. I guess the builtin console is removed completely.

You should use the gogo console that has become a de-facto standard. You can find information about it at the link above.

Answer (score 0):

You can also change the directory where the eclipse plugins reside and issue a command similar to:

```
java -Dosgi.bundles=.\org.apache.felix.gogo.shell_1.1.0.v20180713-1646.jar@start,.\org.apache.felix.gogo.command_1.0.2.v20170914-1324.jar@start,.\org.apache.felix.gogo.runtime_1.1.0.v20180713-1646.jar@start,.\org.eclipse.equinox.console_1.3.100.v20180827-1235.jar@start -jar org.eclipse.osgi_3.13.100.v20180827-1536.jar -console
```

This will start the osgi console