# Run latest Equinox with gradle/maven tool

Tags: java, maven, gradle, equinox

An answer to [How to start osgi console (Equinox)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25733843/how-to-start-osgi-console-equinox) suggest that more files are needed than just `org.eclipse.osgi.jar`

How to run (i.e. download and execute, or copy to a distribution folder) with maven or gradle?

Answer (score 0):

Download the equinox jars adding the below dependencies in your pom.xml

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.eclipse.osgi</groupId>
    <artifactId>org.eclipse.osgi</artifactId>
    <version>3.7.1</version>
</dependency>
```

Start the OSGI runtime and login to the documented port (6667 for Felix) to use the CLI

The console could also be started using the following commands

```
java -jar org.eclipse.osgi_3.2.0.jar -console
```

Comment: That unfortunately will not get the latest 3.10 equinox and not solve referenced question