# Felix GoGo Shell throws MalformedURLException: unknown protocol: bundleresource in Equinox

Tags: osgi, equinox, gogo-shell, embedded-osgi

I am writing [an extension](https://github.com/CoastalHacking/semiotics-extensions) to a Java application called [ZAP](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/OWASP_Zed_Attack_Proxy_Project). The extension is a fat/uber jar that has the Equinox bundle (`org.eclipse.osgi`) [inlined](https://github.com/CoastalHacking/semiotics-extensions/tree/master/dependencies/us.coastalhacking.semiotics.extensions.dependencies.osgi). Additional [bundles](https://github.com/CoastalHacking/semiotics-extensions/tree/master/dependencies/us.coastalhacking.semiotics.extensions.dependencies.runtime) are also included in this jar, within a sub-directory `bundles`.  The OSGi framework is being launched as outlined in [How To Embed OSGi](http://njbartlett.name/2011/07/03/embedding-osgi.html).

I'm trying to get Felix GoGo shell to work, following [the steps outlined](http://help.eclipse.org/mars/topic/org.eclipse.platform.doc.isv/guide/console_shell.htm?cp=2_0_3_8) via Eclipse's "Console Shell" documentation. It specifies the following required bundles:

- `org.apache.felix.gogo.command`
- `org.apache.felix.gogo.runtime`
- `org.apache.felix.gogo.shell`
- `org.eclipse.equinox.console`

In addition to Equinox / `org.eclipse.osgi`. Since Equinox is not on the class path, I set `org.osgi.framework.system.packages.extra` configuration to the `Export-Package` value specified by Equinox's bundle, visible [here](https://github.com/CoastalHacking/semiotics-extensions/blob/a57e1480b4f1244854bdd05fdbdc82c48c7b8926/common/src/main/java/us/coastalhacking/semiotics/extensions/common/Launcher.java#L194).

Once the framework is in the ACTIVE state, I see the following stack trace in Eclipse (or via the command line outside of Eclipse):

```
Starting OSGi framework...
OSGi framework state: 32
gogo: MalformedURLException: unknown protocol: bundleresource
java.net.MalformedURLException: unknown protocol: bundleresource
  at java.net.URL.<init>(URL.java:593)
  at java.net.URL.<init>(URL.java:483)
  at java.net.URL.<init>(URL.java:432)
  at java.net.URI.toURL(URI.java:1089)
  at org.apache.felix.gogo.shell.Shell.readScript(Shell.java:209)
  at org.apache.felix.gogo.shell.Shell.source(Shell.java:192)
  at org.apache.felix.gogo.shell.Shell.gosh(Shell.java:109)
  at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
  at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
  at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497)
  at org.apache.felix.gogo.runtime.Reflective.invoke(Reflective.java:137)
  at org.apache.felix.gogo.runtime.CommandProxy.execute(CommandProxy.java:82)
  at org.apache.felix.gogo.runtime.Closure.executeCmd(Closure.java:477)
  at org.apache.felix.gogo.runtime.Closure.executeStatement(Closure.java:403)
  at org.apache.felix.gogo.runtime.Pipe.run(Pipe.java:108)
  at org.apache.felix.gogo.runtime.Closure.execute(Closure.java:183)
  at org.apache.felix.gogo.runtime.Closure.execute(Closure.java:120)
  at org.apache.felix.gogo.runtime.CommandSessionImpl.execute(CommandSessionImpl.java:89)
  at org.apache.felix.gogo.shell.Activator.run(Activator.java:75)
  at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

It seems the Equinox URL handlers are not being used by GoGo. I noticed the following packages related to them were not in Equinox's `Export-Package`:

- `org.eclipse.osgi.storage.url`
- `org.eclipse.osgi.storage.url.bundleresource`
- `org.eclipse.osgi.storage.url.bundleentry`

So I also included those in the `org.osgi.framework.system.packages.extra` package list. That didn't help.

The bundles are installed and started without any obvious errors otherwise.

How do I make GoGo utilize Equinox's custom URL handlers?

### Update 1: Maybe Red Herring

In random troubleshoot I wanted to execute the final shaded jar as outlined [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35922571). I copied both the original `org.eclipse.osgi` bundle and the shaded jar in the same directory. There's a `configuration/config.ini` specifying the bundles to load.

Executing the stock bundle brings up the console:

```
$ java -cp ~/.p2/pool/plugins/org.eclipse.osgi_3.11.0.v20160121-2005.jar org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter -console
osgi> ss
"Framework is launched."


id  State       Bundle
0 ACTIVE      org.eclipse.osgi_3.11.0.v20160121-2005
1 ACTIVE      org.apache.felix.gogo.runtime_0.10.0.v201209301036
2 ACTIVE      org.apache.felix.gogo.command_0.10.0.v201209301215
3 ACTIVE      org.apache.felix.gogo.shell_0.10.0.v201212101605
4 ACTIVE      org.eclipse.equinox.console_1.1.200.v20150929-1405
osgi> exit
Really want to stop Equinox? (y/n; default=y)
```

Executing the shaded jar, not so much:

```
java -cp semiotics-alpha-1.zap org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter -console
java.lang.NullPointerException: A null service reference is not allowed.
  at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.framework.BundleContextImpl.getService(BundleContextImpl.java:617)
  at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.startup(EclipseStarter.java:299)
  at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:231)
  at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.main(EclipseStarter.java:208)
```

This could be a total red herring... I'm very ignorant on OSGi, this being my first hands-on experience with it. However, I would expect the shaded jar to execute no differently than the stock Equinox jar. Since I don't understand why there's a difference I'm gonna dig there for lack of any better spots to dig...

### Update 2: Equinox on Classpath Works Around Issue

I added the Equinox bundle to ZAP's classpath via its `lib` directory and removed it from being inlined into the extension jar. Doing this and adjusting the `ServiceLoader.load` call to not include a class loader (defaulting to system class loader) works:

```
Starting bundle: org.apache.felix.gogo.shell_0.10.0.v201212101605 [1]
Starting bundle: org.eclipse.equinox.console_1.1.100.v20141023-1406 [2]
Starting bundle: org.apache.felix.gogo.command_0.10.0.v201209301215 [3]
Starting bundle: org.eclipse.emf.ecore_2.11.2.v20160208-0816 [4]
Starting bundle: org.eclipse.emf.common_2.11.1.v20160208-0816 [5]
Starting bundle: org.apache.felix.gogo.runtime_0.10.0.v201209301036 [6]
osgi> ss
"Framework is launched."


id  State       Bundle
0 ACTIVE      org.eclipse.osgi_3.11.0.v20160121-2005
1 ACTIVE      org.apache.felix.gogo.shell_0.10.0.v201212101605
2 ACTIVE      org.eclipse.equinox.console_1.1.100.v20141023-1406
3 ACTIVE      org.apache.felix.gogo.command_0.10.0.v201209301215
4 ACTIVE      org.eclipse.emf.ecore_2.11.2.v20160208-0816
5 ACTIVE      org.eclipse.emf.common_2.11.1.v20160208-0816
6 ACTIVE      org.apache.felix.gogo.runtime_0.10.0.v201209301036
osgi>
```

The underlying issue might be how the jar is being inlined, possibly related to the `MANIFEST.MF` file. Possibly related, I now don't need to supply a value for `org.osgi.framework.system.packages.extra`.

I'm going to leave this question unanswered since the original point was to include the OSGi library as a shaded artifact. Maybe bndtools can help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, it seems the lack of a descriptive `META-INF/MANIFEST.MF` was the culprit:

- Removed (`jar uM...`) then updated (`jar um...`) the shaded jar's `MANIFEST.MF` to be a copy of Equinox's manifest, modifying the `Bundle-Version` number to end in `1766` versus `1700`.
- Removed Equinox from ZAP's classpath

Then I loaded the extension as is. GoGo shell starts:

```
osgi> 13177 [AWT-EventQueue-0] INFO org.parosproxy.paros.control.Control  - New Session
ss
"Framework is launched."


id  State       Bundle
0 ACTIVE      org.eclipse.osgi_3.10.102.v20160118-1766
1 ACTIVE      org.apache.felix.gogo.runtime_0.10.0.v201209301036
2 ACTIVE      org.eclipse.emf.common_2.11.1.v20160208-0816
3 ACTIVE      org.apache.felix.gogo.shell_0.10.0.v201212101605
4 ACTIVE      org.eclipse.equinox.console_1.1.100.v20141023-1406
5 ACTIVE      org.apache.felix.gogo.command_0.10.0.v201209301215
6 ACTIVE      org.eclipse.emf.ecore_2.11.2.v20160208-0816
osgi>
```

I see the system bundle ends in the same modified version number, so it's honoring the added `MANIFEST.MF`. So the underlying issue was an incomplete system bundle manifest. Copying an existing one (Equinox's) works well enough. It also works for a straight commandline test:

```
$ java -cp semiotics-alpha-1.zap org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter -console
osgi> exit
Really want to stop Equinox? (y/n; default=y)  y
```

Dunno if I'll use this approach or not. At least I know what I need to do **if** I want to use this approach.